# SDP in 183 Session in progress

Tags: sip, sdp

I'm looking at different sip dialogs, and when I see 183 instead of 180 there is SDP that comes along with it. My question is, what is the purpose of SDP in 183 session progress?
In order for UAS to send media it only must know the IP:PORT of UAC, but SDP in 183 is advertising the IP:PORT of UAS, what kind of data (RTP/UDP) we can actually send to UAS before 200ok/ACK?
I'm trying to understand the purpose of SDP in 183 since it's not needed in order to send any media to UAC (such as ads, music, etc). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The SIP design was thought of with the interop telecommunication protocol that existed previously. Remind SIP is the signaling protocol and the Session Description Protocol (SDP) describes the media.

On the one hand, interoperability between ISDN and SIP has proven to be necessary, hence the need for signaling in media.
Historically in telecom, the call progress toward the called party was provided by in-band tone indications.
It is called early media and is not related to early offer.

Early media is used for a few usages :

a)  Intereaction with  IVR (Voice automaton - interactive voice response) without answering your call (no charging).

b) Report telco errors without answering your call (no charging).
ex: The number you dialed is not   ...

c) Other cases like interop with older analog PSTN and so on.

On the other hand, SIP took a new approach to negotiating with the media and provided early offer and late offer.

The resulting complexity is confusing and your question is justified and a precise and gradual response is needed.

First, the idea of putting SDP in the message body of an `INVITE` request - this is called an early-offer.
In terms of media, the caller offers their options (media, codecs etc)  and waits for the called party to decide which option to choose.
*Note that early offer gives the power of choosing the media over to the called party.*

Second, for any reason the caller does not want to provide an early offer but wants to choose the media option -this is called late-offer.
`INVITE` is sent without SDP and the called party provide the initial offer in a `200 Ok with SDP` then the caller responds back with an `ACK with SDP`.
*Note that with this change in SDP order, the caller decides which media option will be used.*

Next step, let's introduce `180 Ringing` which is used to alert the caller that the called is ringing. The `180` response most of the time does not carry SDP body, and the device receiving this response usually initiate a local ringback tone.

Now, let's introduce `183 Session Progress` which indicates two things:

1. There is an interop between SIP and another telecom network, let's say ISDN.
2. In-band signaling is used either for a), b) or c).  The end user must listen to the early media.
   In addition, `183` could be used to provide distant ringback tone to the caller.

In summary, `183 session progress` provides headers and media that may be used to convey more infos about the call.
It should be used with interop between networks.
It is quite often recommanded to use 183/PRACK for a robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

One such purpose would be ICE (RFC8445): the information in de SDP body part is used to determine the actual IP:PORT combination to use when audio has to travel through one or more NATs.